# Function conversion of argument did not succeed when calling WCF service

Tags: wpf, list, wcf, type-conversion

I have a WCF service with this function :

```
namespace PortfolioSerivce
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
         [OperationContract]
         bool CreateOrders(List<OrderDTO> ListOrder);
    }
}
```

and here its code

```
    public bool CreateOrders(List<OrderDTO> ListOrder)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

The class `OrderDTO` is defined as below :

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]        
    public char OrderType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float OrderedQty { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float PreUNitCost { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float PostUnitCost { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float MarketPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float ClientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float SecurityId { get; set; }
}
```

In WPF, I have a function in which I want to pass a list to the WCF function:

```
    internal bool RemoteCreateOrders(List<Position> securityMarketDTO)
    {
        List<OrderDTO> ListOrders = new List<OrderDTO>();
        Tools.MyRemoteService.CreateOrders((List<OrderDTO>)ListOrders);
        return true;
    }
```

When I compile I got those errors :

> The best overloaded method match for 'PortfolioView.PortfolioService.Service1Client.CreateOrders(PortfolioView.PortfolioService.OrderDTO[])' has some invalid arguments
>
> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'PortfolioView.PortfolioService.OrderDTO[]'

What is the problem here, as I send a list of `OrderDTO` from my app and in WCF I declared as parameter a list of `OrderDTO`. What conversion should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  you exception , you Service1Client's method CreateOrders needs a variable of type OrderDTO[], while you pass List.

Please pass the variable of right type , use ListOrders.ToArray to convert list to array.

Or if you want to pass List, please let vs generate List for collection when you add service reference.

[image]

When adding service reference using vs, you could click advanced at the bottom, and then your could configure Collection type.

Comment: But from the code I wrote `public bool CreateOrders(List<OrderDTO> ListOrder)` so I did not defined a table. I did not understand;